# How to programmatically open the Special Character palette?

Tags: front-end, palettes

I can't seem to find a way to programmatically open the special characters palette found in the **Insert** menu in *Mathematica*.

Is there a way to do this?  Usually there is a frontend token one can use... but I can't seem to find one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following expression will open the special characters palette:

```
FrontEndExecute[{FrontEnd`NotebookOpen["SpecialCharacters.nb"]}]
```

This expression was extracted from `MenuSetup.tr`:

```
{ $InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", "TextResources", $OperatingSystem
, "MenuSetup.tr"
} //
FileNameJoin //
FindList[#, "Special Character..."]& //
First

(*
    MenuItem["&Special Character...",
      FrontEndExecute[{FrontEnd`NotebookOpen["SpecialCharacters.nb"]}]],
*)
```